# Ansible wildcard condition

Tags: ansible

I am using `ansible` version `1.6.6`. My remote server `CentOs 6.4 minimal`. On remote server, `Python 2.6.6` is installed. So I want to install `2.7.*` on remote server.

I have to upgrade it to `2.7.*`. I found a tutorial to install it. It is on right here [Python2.7 Installation on Centos via yum](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2013/02/14/setting-up-django-and-python-2-7-on-red-hat-enterprise-6-the-easy-way/)

My some other remote servers might be ubuntu or another Centos which is already installed `Python version 2.7.*`. So this must be conditional. But I don't know what python 2.7 version is really gonna be installed. It might be `2.7.3`, `2.7.4` or later. I have to use some wildcard condition like;

```
- name: Check python version
  command: python -V
  register: python_version

- debug: var=python_version.stderr
- name: Install Python2.7
  ......
  when: (ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux') and python_version.stderr != 2.7.*
```

Is there a way to use wildcard condition for such situation?

Comment: is there a reason why you're checking against .stderr? I would assume that the python -V command sends it's output to .stdout

Comment: I debugged it and I saw it is in stderr, It is seen also strange to me but I don't know why.

Comment: nevermind :-) What odd behaviour.. http://bugs.python.org/issue18338

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found it on deep search in Ansible documentation; http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html#register-variables;

it can be done with function `find('your_part')` like;

```
when:  python_version.stderr.find('2.7') != 1 and (ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux')
```

This will check whether it contains 2.7 string in it.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an excellent use case for Ansible's `match` function:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings

In your particular example you would use:

```
when: python_version.stderr is not match("2.7\..*") and (ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux')
```